# Android Studio C++ inline compiler doesn't understand smart pointer upcasting

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

My Android Studio inline compiler shows me an error when passing an `unique_ptr` of a derived class to a function expecting an `unique_ptr` of a parent class. But the code compiles as I was expecting.

[image]

The error message from the code snippet above:

```
Parameter type mismatch: Class 'std::unique_ptr<B>' is not compatible with class 'std::unique_ptr<A>'
```

I guess is this a bug, related to Android Studio ? I was wondering if there was an options for this error checker, couldn't find anything

EDIT: Note that this code compiles with no errors from the compiler (the error I quoted is from the Android Studio's real time error checker). You can check the code here: https://ideone.com/xlUsKs

Comment: Please post code as text - not as image. It's impossible to copy/paste such code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. I posted an image to illustrate Android Studio's error checker behaviour. Here is an ideone link where you can easily check the code: https://ideone.com/xlUsKs

Comment: Well, the error message is, typically, sufficient, which you pasted, so we don't need see red squiggly lines, to know that there was an error. EDIT: Oh, I get it, it's intellisense thing, rather than compilation failure. Intellisense is not perfect, and it chokes on some specific code, once in a while, which is not limited to one specific IDE. Just take the output, that intellisense gives you with a grain of salt, especially, if compilation succeeds.

Comment: It is for better illustrating the fact that the IDE highlights an error while there is not really one.

Comment: Many people seems to not have understand correctly, maybe I put the wrong words ? "inline compiler" "real time error checker" I don't quiet know how is this named , "Intellisense" is better ?

Comment: The most accurate term is **code inspection**. You can modify your inspection settings (e.g. to switch rules off) by going to `Preferences->Editor->Inspection->C++`